What are the mistakes have done in the router localhost:4000/rooms/book/1?
const express = require("express");
const { body, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

const app = express();
const PORT = 4000;

app.use(express.json());

const rooms = [];
const booking = [];

// creating room
app.post(
  "/rooms/create",
  [
    body("seatsAvailable").notEmpty().isInt(),
    body("amenities").notEmpty().isArray(),
    body("pricePerHour").notEmpty().isFloat(),
  ],
  (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).send({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const room = {};
    room.id = rooms.length + 1;
    Object.assign(room, req.body);
    rooms.push(room);
    res.status(201).send(room);
  }
);

// booking rooms

app.post(
  "/rooms/book/:roomId",
  [
    body("customerName").notEmpty().isAlphanumeric(),
    body("dateOfBooking").notEmpty().isDate(),
    body("startTime").notEmpty().isString(),
    body("endTime").notEmpty().isString(),
    body("seatsRequired").notEmpty().isInt(),
  ],
  (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).send({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    if (rooms.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).send({ message: "No rooms available" });
    }
    const roomId = req.params.roomId;
    const room = rooms.find((room) => room.id == parseInt(roomId));
    if (!room) {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .send({ message: `Room is not found with number ${roomId}` });
    }

    console.log(room);
  }
);

// get rooms
app.get("/rooms", (req, res) => {
  res.send(rooms);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("server connected successfully!");
});



I am trying to create an hall booking apis. In the code below, when I make request to the endpoint in postman to test the router I got the following is in terminal and I couldn't find the mistakes that I did.
error in terminal:
node index.js 
server connected successfully!
SyntaxError: Expected ',' or '}' after property value in JSON at position 54
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (/home/shri/Desktop/Roadmap-Day38-Hall-Booking-API/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:92:19)
    at /home/shri/Desktop/Roadmap-Day38-Hall-Booking-API/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:128:18
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:206:9)
    at invokeCallback (/home/shri/Desktop/Roadmap-Day38-Hall-Booking-API/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:238:16)
    at done (/home/shri/Desktop/Roadmap-Day38-Hall-Booking-API/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:227:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/shri/Desktop/Roadmap-Day38-Hall-Booking-API/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:287:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)



Here is url request:
method: POST
localhost:4000/rooms/book/1
Here is my request body
{
    "customerName": "Jeeva",
    "dateOfBooking": 12-04-2024,
    "startTime": "10.00 AM",
    "endTime": "1.00 PM",
    "seatsRequired": 2
}


Kindly help me to figure out the issue. Thanks

12-04-2024 is not a valid json value. Should be "12-04-2024"

I changed the request body {     "customerName": "Jeeva",     "dateOfBooking": "12-04-2024",     "startTime": "10.00 AM",     "endTime": "1.00 PM",     "seatsRequired": 2 } but it raises validation error

It says some syntax error in line 54

In the code change this


body("customerName").notEmpty().isAlphanumeric(),
    body("dateOfBooking").notEmpty().isDate(),
    body("startTime").notEmpty().isString(),
    body("endTime").notEmpty().isString(),
    body("seatsRequired").notEmpty().isInt(),



to this


body("customerName").notEmpty().isAlphanumeric(),
    body("dateOfBooking").notEmpty().isDate(),
    body("startTime").notEmpty().isString(),
    body("endTime").notEmpty().isString(),
    body("seatsRequired").notEmpty().isInt()



All I did was remove the last comma as there was not a value after it
EDIT:
Change also the other comma from this


body("seatsAvailable").notEmpty().isInt(),
    body("amenities").notEmpty().isArray(),
    body("pricePerHour").notEmpty().isFloat(),



To this


body("seatsAvailable").notEmpty().isInt(),
    body("amenities").notEmpty().isArray(),
    body("pricePerHour").notEmpty().isFloat()



Hope this helped!

actually, after removing the comma, when I save it, the comma is placed by default by vscode

but when commenting out  body("dateOfBooking").notEmpty().isDate(), and not including  "dateOfBooking":12-04-2024, the code works well

Remove the last comma from your validations.
body("customerName").notEmpty().isAlphanumeric(),
    body("dateOfBooking").notEmpty().isDate(),
    body("startTime").notEmpty().isString(),
    body("endTime").notEmpty().isString(),
    body("seatsRequired").notEmpty().isInt()


The comma is placed as default one by vscode when saving it

I got where I had made the mistake. It is about how I validate date field.
when I change this body("dateOfBooking").notEmpty().isDate(), to body("dateOfBooking").notEmpty().isDate({format: "DD-MM-YYYY"}), it worked as expected. Thanks for all of your help.
